# Retrieving a value from a HTML5 slider with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble retrieving a value from a HTML5 slider using JQuery.  Here is my code:

**JQuery:**

```
  // Retrieve the value from slider one
  $("#submit").on("click", function(evt) {
      var sliderValue = $('#slider01').attr('value');
      alert("The value of slider 1 is: " + sliderValue);
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
  <input id="slider01" type="range" name="slider1" min="0" max="10" value="5">
  <span id="value">0</span>
```

It keeps telling me in the alert box that the value is 5 no matter where I move the slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
var sliderValue = $('#slider01').attr('value');
```

to this:

```
var sliderValue = $('#slider01').val();
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the quick response!  The reason I used the `attr` function was because my JQuery exercises state that it returns the current value of that attribute.  There seems to be quite a lot of functions that do similar jobs in JQuery.

Comment: @user1574598 that may have been try for old version of jQuery

Comment: if you have solved your problem accept the answer please @user1574598

Comment: Sorry, thanks for your help.  Yes the video tutorials I am watching are from around 2010.